# Which tree are more productive?(height 3 B-tree or height 4 B+tree)

Tags: data-structures, tree, b-tree

I was ask a question by interviewer in last week.

The question is : Which tree are more productive?(height 3 B-tree or height 4 B+tree)

I know different B-tree between B+tree. But I've no idea for this question.
I hope somebody can give me some idea, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Did the interviewer define what "productive" means? Were there other bits of information provided, like did both trees contain the same number of elements? To me, this sounds like an open-ended question, which is something interviewers like to do. They don't expect a simple answer, but rather, they're testing your ability to ask questions and participate in a design discussion.

Comment: You write *"thank you for your help"* but don't even react to the first comment...

Comment: @boneill Nope. I said "let me see...", and I was silent for a while, I said "I've no idea". Then, he said "It's ok, next question....". In your opinion, what specific questions should I ask to further understand the interviewer's questions?

Comment: @trincot I'm sorry about that I don't check the alerts very often in here.

Comment: what do you mean by "productive" ?

Comment: @Nur I think he probably means which tree can use less time complexity to find the data. I didn't get other information from him :(

Comment: It depends, You need to ask them,  "do you need to access next element, when you find a node?", as you know b-tree is sorted , b+tree is used when you need iterations,  "Is there same number of element in both tree ?"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Nur got it! If I meet the same question in the following interview, I'll ask more details about the question. Thank you for your idea.